# Rails has_many through missing column id with namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm sure im doing something bone-headed here, but it's not hitting me.

```
# models/admin/host.rb
class Admin::Host < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :admin_host_users, class_name: 'Admin::HostUser'
  has_many :users, through: :admin_host_users

# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :admin_host_users, class_name: 'Admin::HostUser'
  has_many :admin_hosts, through: :admin_host_users

# models/admin/host_user.rb
class Admin::HostUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin_host, class_name: 'Admin::Host', foreign_key: 'admin_host_id'
  belongs_to :user

# schema.rb
create_table "admin_host_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "admin_host_id"
  t.bigint "user_id"
end
```

When calling `host.users`:

```
> h.users
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column admin_host_users.host_id does not exist)
LINE 1: ..."users"."id" = "admin_host_users"."user_id" WHERE "admin_hos...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "admin_host_users" ON "users"."id" = "admin_host_users"."user_id" WHERE "admin_host_users"."host_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

Any thoughts as to why it's expecting the column name to be `host_id`?

Comment: Try adding the `inverse_of` option to your `:admin_host_users` association. Like `has_many :admin_host_users, class_name: 'Admin::HostUser', inverse_of: :admin_host`

Comment: @KULKING nah that makes no difference

Comment: Can you post the result of `host.admin_host_users.to_sql` ?

Comment: @KULKING sure thing: `=> "SELECT \"admin_host_users\".* FROM \"admin_host_users\" WHERE \"admin_host_users\".\"host_id\" = 2"`

Comment: @KULKING Um, so i added the foreign key to `  has_many :admin_host_users, class_name: 'Admin::HostUser', foreign_key: 'admin_host_id'` and it appears to be working now

Comment: I just posted the same answer just before your comment :sweat_smile:

Comment: lol yea... jinx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the `foreign_key` in your `has_many` association.

So, in your `Admin::Host` model:

```rb
has_many :admin_host_users, class_name: 'Admin::HostUser', foreign_key: 'admin_host_id'
```

Also leave the foreign_key in `Admin::HostUser` model as that will be used when you do something like `host_user.admin_host`